# How do I save an image in Matlab such that I get my specified output dimensions?

Tags: image, matlab, save, matlab-figure

I have the following code:

```
%# Read image
I = imread('img2.png');    

%# Extract central portion of image
[ny, nx] = size(I);

P = I(round(ny/2)-120:round(ny/2)+120, round(nx/2)-120:round(nx/2)+120);

imgComb = [P P; P P];
myFig = figure; imshow(imgComb);
myFig.PaperUnits = 'centimeters';
myFig.PaperPosition = [0 0 15.24 7.62];
myFig.PaperPositionMode = 'manual';

%# save image
%imwrite(imgComb, ' myImage.tiff');
print('myImage', '-dtiff')
```

If I use the `imwrite` function, I get the image (but not the figure) saved. However, when I copy the figure for instance to a word document, I do not obtain the specified output dimensions of the image.

If I use the `print` function, I get the desired output dimensions of the figure but not the image.

How do I save the image (not the figure) such that I get my specified output dimensions as above?

[image]

Comment: Note: word resizes the figures, you can have any original size and then resize it. When saving images for quality, the size is generally defined with ppi, for example.

Comment: Thank you @Ander Biguri. I do not intend to tamper with the size/resolution after processing in Matlab. If i understand you correctly, does it mean there isn't any way to achieve what i want except that i would have to resize in word?

Comment: There may be a way of doing it. But perhaps (just perhasp) you may be taking the complicated route. Good question anyway. I suggest having a look at `export_fig`, it may do the job

Comment: Just drag the corner of the figure in Word to the right size. There is nothing wrongs about that.

Comment: I think `imwritesize` could do this, but i was told  (just as Cris Luengo suggested) that there is nothing wrong with rescaling in word, ppt, pub, corel draw, etc. Thank you guys for your help.